# How to create a detailed and categorized tibble out of an easy tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

My question is how can I create a tibble or data frame which should look like the following:

[***how it should look***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVfwD.jpg)

So the JEL codes should be grouped by letters, by letters and first number and then per letter and two numbers. Util now I was not able to extract the letters out of JEL_codes, because it is a list and when I do extract it this list is longer than the list of the volumes and I cant create a tibble anymore.

At the moment I have tibble that looks like this where I got observations of JEL_codes and the volume:

[***how it looks right now***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC1gK.png)

Maybe as a first step I would seperate the observations so that one JEL code matches with a volume , so no thwo JEL codes are in a row.
Anything that brings me a little bit further helps me, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

**BTW**: To help us to help you could you please make your issue reproducible by sharing a sample of your **data**, the **code** you tried and the **packages** you used? See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) To post your data type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble(
  JEL_codes = list(c("Q54", "Q58"), c("Q15", "Q25"), "H23"),
  volume = c(2, 3, 6)
)

d %>% 
  unnest(JEL_codes) %>% 
  mutate(JEL_code1 = gsub("^([A-Z]).+", "\\1", JEL_codes),
         JEL_code2 = gsub("^([A-Z]\\d).+", "\\1", JEL_codes)) %>% 
  select(JEL_code1, JEL_code2, JEL_code3 = JEL_codes, volume) %>%
  pivot_longer(-volume, names_to = "foo", values_to = "jel_code") %>% 
  select(-foo) %>% 
  count(jel_code, volume, sort = TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = volume, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  arrange(jel_code)
#> # A tibble: 11 x 4
#>    jel_code   `2`   `3`   `6`
#>    <chr>    <int> <int> <int>
#>  1 H            0     0     1
#>  2 H2           0     0     1
#>  3 H23          0     0     1
#>  4 Q            2     2     0
#>  5 Q1           0     1     0
#>  6 Q15          0     1     0
#>  7 Q2           0     1     0
#>  8 Q25          0     1     0
#>  9 Q5           2     0     0
#> 10 Q54          1     0     0
#> 11 Q58          1     0     0
```